# I can't find docker containers config.v2.json file on mac docker desktop

Tags: docker

macOS 12.6.8

docker desktop v4.22.1

engine: 24.0.5

I found some tutorials online to modify port mappings,They all mentioned this file, but I can't find it

```
'/var/lib/docker/containers/{id}/config.v2.json'
```

I run a Centos using:

```
docker run -d  --privileged=false --name  hadoop1 -h hadoop1  -v /Users/aa/Desktop/hadoop/hadoop1/sys/fs:/sys/fs/cgroup  --net hadoopnetwork --ip 192.168.0.1  centos:centos7.8.2003 /usr/sbin/init
```

I am a newcomer to Docker, can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: When you say "modify port mappings", what are you trying to do?  Manually editing Docker-internal files doesn't seem like a good approach; I'd normally expect to delete the existing container and recreate it with new options (this should be completely routine).

Comment: “delete the existing container and recreate it with new options” It can solve problems. But , Can I solve the problem by modifying the container configuration file? such as modify the 'config.v2.json' file? Many tutorials on the internet have mentioned it, but I cannot find it. Has it been removed in the new docker version?